# How To Fix Hair Particles

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

Hey everyone. It's me again and I have another problem. I've been following the Blender Guru's realistic fur tutorial,but when I clump the fur and use the threshold,something weird happens. Instead of behaving like in the image above,they act like the example below. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not,but it's very annoying and I need help fixing it.

[image]

Comment: Are you using simple children or advanced?

Comment: They are advanced.

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your particle settings, but how about trying to add location dependent and random rough in the children panel?